# Sum of numbers in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I try to sum count with 1 when user clicked on button, but result is : 11

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  quantity : 1
}
this.incrementCount = this.incrementCount.bind(this)
}

incrementCount=()=>{
 this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
    quantity: prevState.quantity + 1
  }));
}
```

Show and button:

```
<Text>{this.state.quantity}</Text>
<Button onPress={this.incrementCount}>
  <Text>+</Text>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parse quantity to integer

```
incrementCount=()=>{
 this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
    quantity: parseInt(prevState.quantity) + 1
  }));
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could do `quantity: +prevState.quantity + 1`

Comment: or just  `quantity: +prevState.quantity + 1`

or  `quantity: 1*prevState.quantity + 1`